# Can google persistent ip ptr resolve to internal address?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Amazon has DNS option for VPC that allows to resolve elastic ip PTR to external and internal addresses depending on the query source.

`dig @8.8.8.8 ec2-54-194-175-41.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. +short
54.194.175.41
dig @10.0.0.2 ec2-54-194-175-41.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. +short
10.0.1.253`

Google compute engine (GCE) ip addresses have PTR like 95.141.251.24.bc.googleusercontent.com. but they do not resolve to internal ip addresses inside google network. Also GCE has metadata server which acts as DNS and resolves c.project.internal records but that is not so elegant as above solution from Amazon.

Is there anything similar to elastic PTR for GCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't provide this sort of split-horizon DNS service today; what you're actually describing is not different PTR addresses, but different A records for public DNS and instance DNS.

Google decided that it would be useful to be able to refer to your other instances by name when within your network, but that would be an undesirable information leak when exposed to the public internet. (Internal - nice name, private IP address; External - generic name, public IP address.)

Comment: There is no name leak in AWS solution, I use it as CNAME for my instances DNS names  but can't do the same with GCE.